# User attribute not working in bash resource of chef recipe

Tags: ruby, bash, chef-infra, recipe

I am trying to run one command as grid user.

Code-1 is not working. Giving permission not available error.

code-2 is working. What is the issue?

Code-1

```
bash "start ora.cssd" do    
    code <<-EOH
        /u01/app/grid/11.2.0.4/bin/crsctl start resource ora.cssd -init
    EOH
    user "grid"
end
```

code-2

```
bash "start ora.cssd" do
    code <<-EOH 
        sudo su - grid -c "/u01/app/grid/11.2.0.4/bin/crsctl start resource ora.cssd -init"
    EOH
end
```

I am not able to understand why bash is not able to run that command as grid user in code-1 snippet

Exact error log for code-1 snippet:

```
Recipe: Oracle11G::startGridservices
  * execute[start ora.cssd] action run[2015-04-21T14:31:43+00:00] INFO: Processing execute[start ora.cssd] action run (Oracle11G::startGridservices line 4)

================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[start ora.cssd]'
================================================================================


Errno::EACCES
-------------
Permission denied - /u01/app/grid/11.2.0.4/bin/crsctl start resource ora.cssd -init
```

========================

i ran the above command with root user and i am not getting permission denied issue.

su -c "/u01/app/grid/11.2.0.4/bin/crsctl start resource ora.cssd -init" grid

CRS-5702: Resource 'ora.cssd' is already running on 'ip-10-10-10-10'
CRS-4000: Command Start failed, or completed with errors.

Comment: Does the order of the `code` and `user` keywords matter? What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: The main difference between the two is that the second one is a login shell (`su -`) which load effetively the use env, the first one is the same as `su -c "command " grid` inheriting the chef env, so I highly suspect there's is an environment variable for this user needed by the script you're running. But the effective error log from chef would help (maybe with a `-l debug` to get more information (extremely verbose)

Comment: I have edited my question with exact error. That particular command is working fine with user grid if i run from command prompt

Comment: @SASI try running it as root with `su -c "the full command" grid` and see what happens (I'm quite sure you'll get an access denied there too as it try to write in home directory or something like this)

Comment: It is asking password for grid user

Comment: @SASI I said as root, if you're not root, `sudo su -c "command" grid`. I really do think you may take advantage reading [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/index.html)

Comment: Please, edit your question, comments are awfull for code formatting and unreadable.

Comment: Please any one let me know reason why user is not working in bash resource..

Comment: @SASI how could we be more explicit than the error message you got got. The problem is not chef but your understanding of linux basics (how su and sudo work, what has to be in suoders.d, etc.)

Comment: @Tensibai I am really confused here.. i am new for this. I am able to run manually same command with that user but with bash resource it is saying permission issue.

Comment: @SASI quoting myself in my first comment: "But the effective error log from chef would help (maybe with a -l debug to get more information "

Comment: @niton you may have formatted the last lines with a code block too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your problem is that you are forgetting to set the group:

```ruby
bash "start ora.cssd" do    
    code <<-EOH
        /u01/app/grid/11.2.0.4/bin/crsctl start resource ora.cssd -init
    EOH
    user "grid"
    group "grid"
end
```

I do not know for sure, but maybe the script is allowed to be run by the `grid` group, but not specifically by the user `grid`. Something like the following:

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 otheruser grid SOMEDATE /u01/app/grid/11.2.0.4/bin/crsctl
```

I mean, `su` changes both the user and the group. And that's not the case of your `bash` resource example, you forgot to set the group.